# How to import a js class in main.js file of a vue.js project and use it in all the components instead of importing in each component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have written some JS classes that I would like to import in the app.js/main.js file of my vue.js project so that I can instantiate them in the components. Right now I am having to import the same JS class in all the components where I need the class individually.

I've tried the import in the main.js file but the components don't recognize it.

in the main.js file, I am importing like as follows

`import Permissions from './Permissions'`

However, when I want to instantiate the Permissions class in my component like

`data() {
permissions: new Permission({
  some object properties...
})
}`

the component doesn't know what `Permissions` is.

How do I let the component know what `Permissions` class is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it in the vue way, you can create your own plugin or mixin. See detailed instructions [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/creating-custom-plugins/)

So, you can create a permissions plugin in permissions-plugin.js

```
import Permissions from './Permissions'

const PermissionsPlugin = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    // This adds the $getPermissions method to all instances
    Vue.prototype.$getPermissions = function(properties) {
      return new Permission({
        some object properties...
      })   
    }
  }
};
```

Then you have to tell vue to use your plugin:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import PermissionsPlugin from './permissions-plugin.js'
import App from './App.vue'

// The plugin is loaded here.
Vue.use(PermissionsPlugin)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

And lastly now from any component you should be able to use your function like:

```
this.$getPermissions(properties)
```

Comment: could you please explain me what went wrong with my answer because you down voted it?

Comment: I apologize, I am new to StackOverflow and I really didn't downvote your answer. Thanks a lot for your help.